# Add error in treap

Tags: c++, oop, tree

i've realised treap and it has method add. So, when i triyng to do in main this

```
int main(){
    nodeptr root=NULL;
    treap bst;
    bst.add(root, 10);
    // bst.add(root, 9);
    // bst.add(root, 8);
    if(bst.find(root, 10)){
        cout<<"OMG";
    }
}
```

It has an error on line `nv->x=x;` So, there is all code for add

```
void treap::add(nodeptr &p, int x){
    nodeptr nv, l, r;
    nv->x=x;
    nv->y=random();
    nv->left=NULL;
    nv->right=NULL;
    split(p, x, l, r);
    p=merge(merge(l, nv), r);
}
```

For find

```
bool treap::find(nodeptr &p, int x){
    if(!p){
        return false;
    }
    if(p->x == x){
        return true;
    }
    else if(x< p->x){
        return find(p->left, x);
    }
    else{
        return find(p->right, x);
    }
}
```

And for merge

```
nodeptr treap::merge(nodeptr l, nodeptr r){
    nodeptr result;
    if (!l){
        result=r;
    }
    else if(!r){
        result=l;
    }
    else if(l->cnt > r->cnt){
        l->right=merge(l->right, r);
        result=l;
    }
    else{
        r->left=merge(l, r->left);
        result=r;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And how i define treap:

```
typedef struct node *nodeptr;
struct node{
    int x;
    long y;
    node* left ;
    node* right ;
    int cnt;
    node(int key=0, long prior=0):  x(key), y(prior), left(NULL), right(NULL), cnt(0)  {}
};

class treap{
public:
    int cnt( nodeptr &p);
    bool find(nodeptr &p, int x);
    void update_cnt(nodeptr &p);
    void split(nodeptr &p, int x, nodeptr &l, nodeptr &r);
    void insert(nodeptr &p, nodeptr &q);
    nodeptr merge(nodeptr l, nodeptr r);
    void deletes(nodeptr &p, int x);
    void add(nodeptr &p, int x);
};
```

Can you explain me, please, why is this error here? Thank you in advance. Sorry if the question is nooby, i am new at oop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line : `nodeptr nv, l, r;` you only create a pointer to node, and it's not pointing to anything useful. You should allocate memory for the node, and make this pointer point to that allocated memory.`nodeptr nv = new node;` (make sure you `delete` that memory)
Better still, you may want to create object controlling lifetime of that node instead of handling memory by hand.